# Is there a way to simultaneously send and receive messages on Python TCP socket?

Tags: python, networking, tcp

I want to implement in Python a client which interacts with a server over TCP. Server works with each connection only for a **fixed amount of time**. For example, 1 second. If client wants to interact with a server for more than 1 second, it will send *heartbeat* message.

Therefore, client must be able to **simultaneously** **receive** messages from server and **send** *heartbeat* request every 0.7 seconds. And I want client to use **only one** TCP socket.

Is there any elegant way to do this?

I've managed to implement it using **socket** module, but using timeouts make sending and receiving messages very huge:

**server.py**

```py
import socket
import time


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 30645))
    sock.listen()

    conn, _ = sock.accept()
    last_heartbeat = time.time()

    sock.settimeout(0.1)

    with conn:
        i = 0
        while True:
            if time.time() - last_heartbeat >= 1.0:
                break

            while True:
                try:
                    conn.sendall(bytes(f"message_{i}\n", "utf-8"))
                    i += 1
                    break
                except TimeoutError:
                    pass

            try:
                message = conn.recv(1024)
                decoded = message.decode("utf-8")

                if decoded == "heartbeat":
                    print("receive heartbeat")
                    last_heartbeat = time.time()
            except TimeoutError:
                pass
```

**client.py**

```py
import socket
import time


def send_heartbeat(sock):
    while True:
        try:
            sock.sendall(b"heartbeat")
            break
        except TimeoutError:
            pass


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 30645))
    sock.settimeout(0.1)

    send_heartbeat(sock)
    last_heartbeat = time.time()

    while True:
        cur_time = time.time()
        if cur_time - last_heartbeat >= 0.75:
            send_heartbeat(sock)
            last_heartbeat = cur_time

        try:
            message = sock.recv(1024)
            print(message.decode("utf-8"), end="")
        except TimeoutError:
            pass
```

Is there any way to make something like **callbacks** on receiving messages?

Comment: A simple approach would be to use one of the implementations in the ```select``` module to wait with timeout until either data can be read without blocking or a timeout occurs. Use the timeout to send your heartbeat.